# Automorphism Group of rational normal curve of degree n

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, algebraic-groups, automorphism-group, projective-varieties

Let $V=\mathbb{C}^2$. $PGL_2(\mathbb{C})$ acts naturally on $V$. This action induces action of $PGL_2$ on $sym^n(V)$.

Let $\iota_n: \mathbb{P}(V)=\mathbb{P}^1\to \mathbb{P}^n=\mathbb{P}(sym^n(V))$ be the natural **Veronese embedding** where line passing through vector $v\in V $ mapped to line passing through vector $v^n\in sym^n(V)$.

It is evident that $PGL_2(\mathbb{C})$ action on $\mathbb{P}(sym^n(V))$ will map $[v^n]$ to $[(g\cdot v)^n]$ hence preserves the image

Im$(\iota_n):=C_n:=\{[v^n] : v\in V\}\subset \mathbb{P}(sym^n(V))$, the **rational normal curve of degree n**.

- Why any automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^n$ fixing $C_n$ point wise has to be identity?
- Why the group G of automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^n$ which preserve $C_n$ is precisely PGL_2?

Comment: Have you made any attempts of your own? Tried any examples (for instance, $n=2$, perhaps)? Or have you done any research (rational normal curves are common objects of study)?

Comment: For your first question, note that the fixed point set of an automorphism of ${\bf P}^n$ is a union of linear subspaces (ie a union of intersections of zero sets of linear homogenous polynomials). If $C_n$ is contained in the zero set of a non zero linear polynomial, then by composing with the Veronese maps you obtain a non zero homogenous polynomial  of degree $d$ on ${\bf P}^1$, which vanishes everywhere. This is does not exist. So if $C_n$ is contained in the fixed set of an automorphism of ${\bf P}^n$, then this fixed set must be all of ${\bf P}^n$.